# how to show an empty template in custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am working on a custom directive that will show the *transcluded* empty template when there is nothing to show in the scope -- as in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BxnmZKeo1RLuL9KDB1Fz).

I could not achieve to remove the empty template in ng-repeat nor I was able to show the empty message only when there is no data. How can I display the empty template when there is nothing to show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I am not sure that it is right way to do it in directive - you'll better show different DIVs inside of your main template.

But here is my idea: instead of transclude, do manual compiling depending on is there any items to show or not.

Here is working (but still little bit dirty) plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/dxUjpeCbSKKjaXqK9qBF?p=preview

Note, that even as I am watching whole list, re-compiling is done only when state (empty/non-empty) is changed.

Note2: It is not full transclusion - scope inside of templates (empty and not empty) will be isolated to directive's scope. You can workaround that by using different compilation or child scopes - there are couple solutions, but they are not related to this question :)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Works like a charm now. http://plnkr.co/edit/c0vGicbbKhYbZ59VsvLE?p=preview

Comment: Tiny note: you can remove "true" parameter from directive's $watch - you're watching length. And as you're using custom elements, don't forget about IE Shiv. But I am glad that you've liked idea :)

Comment: That's right. I will do the clean up while integrating. It seems to me not a bad idea to embed this logic into a directive rather than using an external div outside of directive's scope. Though, I am not quite sure if that is angular way of doing the things.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a directive for this. Just remove the directive from `app.js` and replace the code after buttons with this:

```
  <div ng-hide="things.length">nothing to show here</div>
  <div ng-show="things.length">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="thing in things">thing #{{thing}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Here's the working code: http://plnkr.co/edit/u4FF77y6dhXHj0FQC9Ai?p=preview